# Can I use cellRendererSelector to give each row its own cellRenderer

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to solve this issue:
[Can you specify a different customCellRenderer to different rows in ag-grid Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074232/can-you-specify-a-different-customcellrenderer-to-different-rows-in-ag-grid-angu)

In *ag-grid*'s documentation, I found [something that might help](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/); under the section *Many Renderers One Column*, they have demonstrated something a bit similar to my need (see the [plunker project](https://plnkr.co/edit/P5suHbMjjVH3knho3B7n?p=preview)).

In this particular part:

```js
cellRendererSelector: function(params) {
  var moodDetails = {
    component: 'moodCellRenderer'
  };

  var genderDetails = {
    component: 'genderCellRenderer',
    params: {
      values: ['Male', 'Female']
    }
  };

  if (params.data.type === 'gender')
    return genderDetails;
  else if (params.data.type === 'mood')
    return moodDetails;
  else
    return null;
}
```

Which works this way:
[image: multiple renderers one column example]

In their example, they render the cell based on a value chosen in another column in the same row.
Intuitively, I tried the following:

```js
if (params.node.id === 1)
    return genderDetails;
else if (params.node.id === 5)
    return moodDetails;
else
    return null;
```

I thought that was supposed to work, but it didn't:

[image: multiple renderers one column implementation]

Any idea why this didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

you almost got it!

the only issue with the code is that `node.id`s are of type `string`, while you try to compare them with `number`s.

to fix it, update the `cellRendererSelector` conditions to test for strings:

```js
if (params.node.id === '1')
    return genderDetails;
else if (params.node.id === '5')
    return moodDetails;
else
    return null;
```

---

note that lenient comparison would also work:

```js
if (params.node.id == 1)
    // and so on...
```

… as the number will be coerced to a string before the comparison.
i'd advise against it though, it can become a pitfall later, when you forget why you've put that `==` in the first place :)